# What's the meaning/history of Snake Eyes' right arm red symbol?

Tags: symbols, gi-joe

This is the symbol in red:

```
█████ █████
███████████
█████ █████
███████████
█████ █████
███████████
```

From [Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SnakeEyeslive.jpg):

[image: SnakeEyes, from the movie G.I Joe the Rise of Cobra (2009)]

Comment: Hexagram 63 - Already Fording https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hexagrams_of_the_I_Ching#Hexagram_63

Comment: I'm voting to leave open as it has importance on a character level. As it isn't too SF/F specific, I recommend migrating it to Movies & TV as that seems to be a better fit.

Answer (score 7):

The symbol is tattoed on the Arashikage Ninja Clan members upon graduation.

It is the hexagram #63 symbol for *Already Fording* ("after completion" and "already completed" or "already done"), composed by the Ba gua triagrams for water (on top) and fire.

It originally appears on *G.I. Joe: A Real American Hero* #21 (March 1984) starring Snake Eyes and Storm Shadow.

- [*I Ching* symbols on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hexagrams_of_the_I_Ching#Hexagram_63)
- *G.I. Joe: A Real American Hero* #21 Review and scans at [majorspoilers.com](http://majorspoilers.com/2012/06/03/retro-review-g-i-joe-a-real-american-hero-21-march-1984/)

Comment: Well done. Thank you for following on with this.

Comment: If you want to add it in, apparently it's usually tattooed on an Arashikage arm in that location on graduation.